# How limit a user to save database in django?

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-mysql

How do i restrict the user to save objects in db

```
class model_name(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   foo = models.CharField(max_length=51)
```

i want to limit the **foo** only for 10 entries per user

i am using **mysql** as a backend

Comment: if you use postgre as backend db, you could use stuff like [ArrayFields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/). And for these arrays, cou could control length, content etc.

Comment: i am using mysql as backend

Comment: Yeah, already noticed, my bad. Maybe you could switch the underlying db depending on your requirements etc. You have always the option to execute code [before a model field becomes saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save), so this could be a useful hack for you too.

Comment: is there any way to validate in forms.py

Comment: If you want to achieve it in form.py, I guess the most intuitive way is to check the number of foo in DB before user insert/update foo.
If num of records>10, response error msg to user.

Comment: can u explain it in code @CK Chen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do

```
class model_name(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   foo = models.CharField(max_length=51)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.__class__.objects.filter(user=self.user).count()>=10:
           return None
       return super(model_name, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
       #return super().save(*args, **kwargs) python3.x
```

You can do the same thing if you are using `forms` by updating `Form.clean` method

```
def clean(self):
    super(MyForm, self).clean()
    if model_name.objects.filter(user=self.cleaned_data['user']).count()>=10:
           raise forms.ValidationError("You have exceeded limit.")
```

Comment: i have tried in form but it wont show validation error

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers yeah i meant that :).

Comment: Hoe you are rendering form? Is it admin ?